# How to set animation when component is deleted or updated

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I want to run an animation when a component is created and when a component is going to be deleted. I know how to set an animation to run when a component is created, like below:

```
 <Animatable.View ref="view" animation="bounceIn">
                <Text>sssdsccssss</Text>
            </Animatable.View>
 ....
```

However, I don't know how I can set an animation when deleted. I used an item of FlatList and I want to run an animation when I pop from the list. I also use `react-native-animatable`.

Comment: There are heaps of tutorials for something like this, EG http://moduscreate.com/react-native-dynamic-animated-lists/ , or simply google React native dynamic list view - I think there's a youtube tutorial too.